# Защищено / защищены 5 кандидатских диссертаций?

Tags: грамматика, согласование, числительные, единственное-множественное-число, количественно-именное-сочетание

Как правильно: *защищено 5 кандидатских диссертаций или защищены пять кандидатских диссертаций*?

Answer (score 3):

Предпочтительный вариант: **защищено 5 кандидатских диссертаций**.

Краткое причастие обозначает пассивное нерасчлененное действие, ед. число подчеркивает совокупность предметов, учитывается препозиция сказуемого.

Пример:  Выпускниками кафедры **защищено** более 40 кандидатских и 12 докторских диссертаций.

Чтобы использовать форму мн. числа, надо **подчеркнуть** расчлененность действия, например: **В разные годы** на кафедре **были защищены** 5 кандидатских диссертаций.

Comment: Подробнее см. http://new.gramota.ru/spravka/letters/64-bolshinstvo

Answer (score 1):

> Как правильно: ***защищено*** 5 кандидатских диссертаций или ***защищены***
>   пять кандидатских диссертаций?

Оба варианта правильны.